# Counting events daily per year

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, count

How to count in python how many events took place in a year, increasing? ( including absent days with the number of events unchanged and summing up the events that repeat) the dates itself are events, 1 date = 1 event

[image: Example:]

Thank you.

I would be grateful for help. Thank you

Comment: can you clarify more.. also add what you have tryed so far..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d.%m.%y')
df.groupby('Date')['value'].sum().resample('D').asfreq().fillna(0).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
Date
2021-01-01    1.0
2021-01-02    1.0
2021-01-03    1.0
2021-01-04    3.0
2021-01-05    4.0
Freq: D, Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you verry much , its worked!

But I had to add another column as 'value'. It would be possible for the date alone to be counted as a +1 value?

Comment: Try change 'galue' to 'date' and sum() to count().

Comment: Only one problem, as my list does not start on January 1 and does not end on December 31, but with a difference of a few days, how could I include the omitted days?

Comment: Use pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq = 'D') , inside groupby.